# complex integral , with singularity ${1\over \pi}$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

How to calculate

$$\int {sin z \over ( z + 1 ) sin {1\over z}}$$
$ on$ $$| z | = {1\over 2}$$

My attempt was to  Binding $\frac{1}{\pi}$ and $0$
by two distinct circle each contains only one trouble point to get

$$\int {sin z \over ( z + 1 ) sin {1\over z}}$$
$ on$ $$|z| = 0.1$$ ..(1)

then multiply by $\frac{{1\over z}}{{1\over z}}$

hence; $$\lim_{z\to 0}{sin z \over ( z + 1 ) sin {1\over z}}$$ is finite

so; ${1\over \pi}$ is removable singularity , therefor

$$\int {sin z \over ( z + 1 ) sin {1\over z}}$$
$ on$ $$|z | = 0.1$$ is equal to $0$

$$\int {sin z \over ( z + 1 ) sin {1\over z}}$$
$on$ $$|z - {1\over \pi} | = 0.1$$ ..(2)

Comment: I am not sure if the integral exists, since $\csc \frac1x$ will blow up infinitely often near zero.

Comment: Your MathJax code is a horrible mess. I cleaned it up. Then you reverted to the former form. Why do you prefer that?

Comment: E.g. you have $\int {sin z \over ( z + 1 ) sin {1\over z}}$ instead of $$ \int {\sin z \over(z+1)\sin{1\over z}}\,dz $$

Comment: Because I was editing the question at the same time as you

Comment: sorry , I don't have enough experience in MathJax code